# Windows 10 keyboard sometimes repeats keys and sometimes ignores keys

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard, dell-precision

Sometimes, as I'm typing, suddenly [A] it ignores keys (it just did it now!) and I have to type them again, then it works, and [B] it sometimes repeats latest keystroke about 20 times.

Problem began a week or two ago.

Windows 10 Pro on DELL Precision 5530, which is 2 months old.

Problllllllllllllllllle  <== this is an example of the problem, wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwh  (<==another!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  which keeps generating multiples keystrokes:   ie:  lll  www  and  !!!)

LOCATION:
Problem happens at home when laptop on dock station wired to keyboard,
and at work when laptop on 2nd dock that has USB dongle to wireless keyboard.

DELL support checked drivers then 2 days ago came and replaced mother board. Problem still occurs.

Comment: What about replacing the keyboard?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue: Dell XPS-15 9570, Thunderbolt TB16 docking station (USB-C, so "dirty contacts" very unlikely to be an issue), all drivers fully up-to-date. Keyboard is Dell KB212-B but can (probably) be eliminated as it worked with no problems on a previous laptop (with a different docking station).

Comment: Same problem here: Dell Latitude 5521, WD19S dock, GREATHTEK KVM. Occurs both with a Cherry MX Board 3.0 and a new Cherry Stream JK-5800 keyboard. I think USB events get lost sporadically, either the key down event (key press ignored) or the key up event (autorepeat). I would guess a Windows / driver bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the issue, it only occurs while the laptop is connected to your docking stations.  It would be *too* coincidental for both docking stations to have the same problem.  The common factor between the two is the docking connector on the laptop itself.  Check the metal pins on the laptop where it connects to the docking station.  Look for bent pins, or some sort of debris stuck in them.  These two issues could be the cause of your intermittent problems.  Depending on your laptop, they might be hidden under the plastic cover that opens as it connects to the dock.  Obviously, carefully remove any debris from the connectors.  If there is a bent pin, you *could* try to bend it back in place.  However, since Dell replaced the motherboard, it sounds like it is under warranty and they should be able to replace the damaged part.

Comment: That's a good idea.  It's a Dell Precision 5530 with a D6000 dock with a USB-C connector.  I'll give it a good scrubbing.